# “Mouse Not Captured In Remote Desktop Sesion” in Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, vhd

I was used Disk2vhd to convert OS (Windows XP) into vhdx format and use Hyper-V Manager to run it as a virtual machine.

I had inserted integration services already and restart the VM, but "Mouse Not Captured In Remote Desktop Session" happened. The mouse cursor is there but cannot use the mouse, only can use keyboard.

I also tried manual insert integration services, but the result is "An error has occurred: One of the update processes returned error code 1603". I unchecked all the integration services (like data exchange, os shutdown) of the setting of the VM in Hyper-V Manager.

Any advice or suggestion? Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Try to reinstall the virtual PC tools. Once it is done, make your guest to use the changed hardware. Here it is described how to accomplish this without a mouse: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dau-blog/2012/02/28/mouse-not-captured-in-remote-desktop-session-when-virtual-pc-vhd-file-runs-in-hyper-v/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please include an excerpt in your answer that actually helps the original poster. In case the links gets dead, your answer should still be able to help out others.

Comment: Sure, already edited.